# Stop content behind Modal window scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, modal-dialog, popup

I have following code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FU1MLYFD0KST. When you click MORE INFO link, the modal window opens up. The problem is that when you scroll inside modal window and get to the end of model window and continue scrolling, the content behind modal window also scrolls. What I need is to prevent that, and only allow modal window content to be scrollable.

Whats best possible solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: When the user opens the modal, I would add a class to the body which stops scrolling in the background. You can do that with js/css.

Comment: any suggestions how to build this code with JS?

Comment: Use the `click` event on the modal link, and then on click, use `element.classList.add('className')`

Comment: Can you apply that code inside my W3schoools sample? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your modified sample:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FU6LYBA3AHR8

As comments have mentioned, you can disable the scrolling of body by changing its overflow property.

These are the changes in the above samples (compared with yours)

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

Comment: works great. Once smaller issue, is that when I test this modal window on phone, and when it shows up, when I scroll modal window all the way down, somehow it mess up content behind again and move it. Is there any fix for mobile phones and tablets too?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I tested on my iphone and it seems to have the following issues:
1. the scroll isn't smooth (though you can fix it with css)
2. as you described, when reached to the end, the body stills get moved
3. (in Safari only), when you scroll the modal, you can see the main body behind the modal for a very brief of time. This is very obvious and user will certainly notice it.

When I display a full screen modal on the phone, I normally put the main content in one div (main div) and modal in another div (modal div) and put them both directly under body....

Comment: .... when page loads, the modal div is hidden. When the modal needs to be displayed, instead of showing it on top of the main div using absolute position (like in your case), I would hide the main div and show the modal div. The difference is, instead of scrolling the absolutely positioned modal div, now you are just scrolling the body. This immediately fix all three issues mentioned above.

Comment: If in both PC and mobile you are displaying the a full screen modal, this is probably the easiest solution. If you are displaying a small modal (not covering the entire screen) on a PC and a full screen modal on mobile. I would suggest some JS to check the screen size. If its big then display a absolutely positioned modal in the center of the screen, if its small screen like a mobile screen then swap the contents of body like described above :)